# Прочитать структуру как массив байт

Tags: c#, .net

Не уверен что такое возможно, но есть ли хоть что-то что может помочь прочитать структуру данных как массив байт? Допустим в си/c++ проблем с таковым нет. Приводим указатель на структуру к типу `const char*` и читаем данные из памяти основываясь на размере.

Это необходимо чтобы отправить структуру в виде массива байт удалённому серверу.

Comment: А смысл? Ну допустим вы загнали структуру в битовый массив, потом прочитали его как последовательность символов юникод и... ? Скорее всего, вы какой то "хак" перетянуть из С в Шарп, но работать он, скорее всего, не будет.

Comment: C# тоже может работать с указателями (в рамках unsafe кода). Опишите подробней, чего именно хотите добиться. Может вам нужна сериализация? В уютном дотнетике она делается элементарно.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: Да, сериализация вполне подойдет, но вот не работал с ней никогда, точнее не использовал в собственных целях.

Comment: Читаете байты. А дальше... `Encoding.GetEncoding(кодировка).GetString(к-во байт)`. Есть второй способ, `StreamReader.ReadLine`. Есть в `Marshal` преобразователи `PtrToStringAnsi` и т п если вы из памяти хотите строку получить.

Comment: Собственно, приведение указателя на структуру в char* и в С++ часто упирается в неопределенное поведение. В .net же не-юникод вообще не считается строкой. Я думаю, ответ - "пожалуйста, не делайте этого".

Comment: может стоит привести пример того что есть, и что хотите получить? Ну и конечно доуказать для чего это нужно!

Comment: "Это необходимо чтобы отправить структуру в виде массива байт удалённому серверу." - а, вот в чем дело, тогда вам действительно нужна бинарная сериализация

Answer (score 4):

Отталкиваясь от последней фразы, напишу ответ.
Для передачи данных на удаленный сервер обычно используется [сериализация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/serialization/). Этот механизм превращает объект в простой тип для передачи по сети. Есть несколько вариантов:

1. Если вас устроит простой [JSON](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) в качестве сериализованной модели, можно пользоваться распространенной библиотечкой [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json), которую можно достать через [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/).
2. Библиотечкой из предыдущего пункта можно также сериализовать в [BSON](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSON), например.
3. Если вас интересует продвинутый вариант сериализации - можно посмотреть на [ProtoBuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) от Google.

В дополнение хочется сказать что для оптимизации пересылки пакетов через сеть лучше их предварительно сжимать. Особенно, если пересылка идёт через HTTP протокол, он поддерживает сжатие c помощью заголовков [Accept-Encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding) и [Content-Encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding).

Comment: Я бы еще добавил [ZeroFormatter](https://github.com/neuecc/ZeroFormatter) и [MessagePack](https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp)

Answer (score 2):

В дополнении к [ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/878504/248572) [@Gordory](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/227032/gordory) могу сказать следующее: при отправке данных по сети Вам по-любому придется работать с массивом байт. Так почему бы не взять блок памяти, отведенный под Вашу структуру, не скопировать его в `byte[]` и не отправить на удаленный сервер, где позже также выгрузить в память?

В случае, если Вы можете полностью отказаться от ссылочных типов данных внутри Вашей структуры, могу предложить Вам именно такой вариант:

```
// Пример пакета
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public unsafe struct Packet
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int ID;

    // Int32 занимает 4 байта
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    // Строка будет храниться внутри структуры в виде фиксированного массива указанной длины
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
    public string Message;

    public Packet(int ID, string Message)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
        // В ANSI 1 символ занимает 1 байт
        this.Message = Message.Length < 129 ? Message : throw new ArgumentException("Message is too long! Max length is 128 characters!", nameof(Message));
    }
}
```

Расширение для демонстрации:

```
public static class StructExtensions
{
    public static byte[] Zip<T>(this T Obj) where T : struct
    {
        // Получим размер, занимаемый объектом
        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(Obj);
        // Сюда будем читать данные
        byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
        // Выделим память и получим указатель на выделенный блок
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
        try
        {
            // Пишем данные структуры в неуправляемый блок памяти
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(Obj, ptr, false);
            // Копируем данные
            Marshal.Copy(ptr, bytes, 0, size);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // Даже в случае ошибки память следует освободить
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
            throw exception;
        }
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        return bytes;
    }

    // Не надо создавать расширения для стандартных типов
    // Здесь я это делаю чисто ради наглядности примера
    public static T Unzip<T>(this byte[] Bytes) where T : struct
    {
        // Получаем дексриптор (указываем, что он закреплен, чтобы сборщик мусора не баловался)
        GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(Bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        try
        {
            // Читаем структуру из блока памяти
            T theStructure = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(T));
            handle.Free();
            // Возвращаем ее
            return theStructure;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // Даже в случае ошибки память следует освободить
            handle.Free();
            throw exception;
        }

    }

}
```

И сам тест:

```
// Инициализируем объект
int uid = 10;
string msg = "Hello, world!";
Packet packet = new Packet(uid, msg);
// Сериализуем его и тут же десериализуем обратно
Packet gotPacket = packet.Zip().Unzip<Packet>(); // ID == 10, Message == "Hello, world!"
```

Заметьте, что метод `.Zip()` вернет нам массив байт длинной `132` (4 на `int` и 128 на `string`), то есть ровно столько, сколько мы и храним
Конечно, данные не сжимаются, но и никакого лишнего *"мусора"* не примешивается, как в случае с сериализацией с помощью [System.Runtime.Serialization](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Суть данного метода в том, что мы просто *копируем* участок памяти, занимаемый структурой, в массив байт. Потом этот массив мы можем точно так же записать в участок памяти, отведенный под аналогичную (хотя бы по размерам) структуру
Именно поэтому важно **отказаться** (в рамках данного метода) от ссылочных типов, ибо на их *"месте"* находятся указатели на иные блоки памяти, где и хранятся их данные. Тем самым в рамках одной и той же машины копирование структуры, которая включает в себя ссылочные типы (вроде массивов), пройдет успешно (если указатели на объекты не сменились), а вот при передаче такого блока на удаленную машину Вы получите результаты весьма неожиданные (точнее,  *неопределенные*)

---

Плюсом (пусть и немного спорным) данного метода является то, что двум связанным сервисам *не нужно* иметь в своем арсенале одну и ту же структуру, взятую из одной и той же сборки! Им необходимо и **достаточно** знать лишь построение этой структуры, а далее можно хоть типы менять)!

К примеру, добавим к нашему прошлому тесту такую структуру:

```
// "Весит" те же 132 байта, что и Packet
public unsafe struct Packet2
{
    // sizeof(int) == sizeof(uint)
    public uint ID;
    // Размер ANSI-строки в 128 символов равен 128 байтам
    public fixed byte Message[128];
}
```

И дополним наш код считывания этими строчками:

```
Packet2 endDataPacket = packet.Zip().Unzip<Packet2>(); // ID == 10, Message == ['H', 'e', ..., '!', '\0', ..., '\0']
string test = new string((sbyte*)endDataPacket.Message); // Hello, world!
```

Как видите, все работает, пусть мы и описали не в точности такую структуру, какую использовали до этого)

---

Надеюсь, мой метод будет Вам полезен, а мой ответ помог Вам разобраться, каким образом средствами `C#` можно считать структуру как массив байт)

Comment: Если запустить тест немного по другому, т.е. попробовать сравнить данные находящиеся в `Message` после десереиализации, то обнаружите что он содержит в себе только первый байт, все остальные буду заполнены нулями. Вот кукую проблему несет в себе `PtrToStruct`. Или по крайней мере у меня всегда так случается.

Comment: @LLENN про это сейчас пишу в Вашем новом вопросе. Ответ уже готов и проблема решена, не волнуйтесь)

Comment: @LLENN, тут `fixed` во второй структуре я для примера привёл. И если десериализовать **в него**, а не **из него**, то все работает как положено)