# Проблема при десериализации объекта при использовании MemoryStream

Tags: c#, .net

Имеется следующий класс:

```
[Serializable]
public class Packet : ISerializable
{
    private byte[] _userId;
    private byte[] _userMessage;

    public Packet()
    {
    }

    public Packet(byte[] userId, byte[] userMessage)
    {
        UserMessage.CopyFrom(ref _userMessage, userMessage);
        UserId.CopyFrom(ref _userId, userId);
    }

    protected Packet(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        UserId = info.GetValue(nameof(_userId), typeof(byte[])).To<byte[]>();
        UserMessage = info.GetValue(nameof(_userMessage), typeof(byte[])).To<byte[]>();
    }

    public byte[] UserId
    {
        get => _userId;
        set => _userId = value;
    }

    public byte[] UserMessage
    {
        get => _userMessage;
        set => _userMessage = value;
    }

    public byte[] ByteData
    {
        get
        {
            byte[] dataBytes;
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                BinaryFormatter fmt = new BinaryFormatter();
                fmt.Serialize(stream, this);
                dataBytes = new byte[stream.GetBuffer().Length];
                dataBytes.CopyFrom(stream.GetBuffer());
            }

            return dataBytes;
        }
    }

    public virtual void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue(nameof(_userId), _userId, typeof(byte[]));
        info.AddValue(nameof(_userMessage), _userMessage, typeof(byte[]));
    }
}
```

И небольшой тест для проверки класса:

```
byte[] userId = new byte[256];

for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
    userId[i] = (byte)i;
}

Packet packet = new Packet(userId, userId);

byte[] data = packet.ByteData;

Packet endDataPacket = new Packet();

using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    BinaryFormatter fmt = new BinaryFormatter();
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    endDataPacket = fmt.Deserialize(stream).To<Packet>();
}
```

И небольшой класс расширений:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T To<T>(this object self)
    {
        return (T) self;
    }

    public static void CopyFrom(this byte[] source, byte[] from)
    {
        Array.Copy(from, source, from.Length);
    }

    public static void CopyFrom(this byte[] self, ref byte[] source, byte[] from)
    {
        if (source == null)
            source = new byte[from.Length];
        source.CopyFrom(from);
    }

    //public static T2 ArrayRemap<T, T2>(this T self, T2 destType) where T2 : IEnumerable<T2> where T : IEnumerable<T>
    //{
    //    T2[] tmpData = new T2[self.To<IEnumerable<T>>().Count()];
    //}
}
```

Далее, при сериализации объекта, все хорошо, но при попытке десериализовать его, получаю следующее:

> Вызвано исключение:
>   "System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException" в mscorlib.dll
>   Исключение типа "System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException"
>   возникло в mscorlib.dll, но не было обработано в коде пользователя
>   Конец потока обнаружен до завершения разбора.

С чем может быть связано такое поведение?

Comment: а после записи в поток и перед десериализацией указатель не нужно в начало устанавливать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как уже успел сказать [@Anatol](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/183842/anatol) в комментариях, ошибка вызвана тем, что Вы не переместили указатель на начало потока и чтение при десериализации начинается с его конца

Чтобы исправить это, достаточно установить свойство [Stream.Position](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.stream.position(v=vs.110).aspx) равным `0` (так как начало записи сериализованного объекта равняется началу самого потока)
То есть:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    BinaryFormatter fmt = new BinaryFormatter();
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    stream.Position = 0; // Ставим указатель на начало
    endDataPacket = fmt.Deserialize(stream).To<Packet>(); // Успешная десериализация
}
```

---

Не совсем относится к вопросу, но хочу заметить одну вещь:

Как я понимаю, Вы создаете некий мост между двумя сервисами, способными принимать/отправлять некоторого вида пакеты

Использовать [System.Runtime.Serialization](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization?view=netframework-4.7.2) для этого не есть хорошо
 Посмотрите: Вы храните `512` байтов информации, а при сериализации получаете `1024` (`data.Length`), что аж в **2 раза** больше (прямой зависимости вроде *1 к 2* нет, но сериализация, используемая Вами, всегда выдает достаточно громоздкие (по отношению к реальным) массивы данных)

В случае, если Вы можете полностью отказаться от ссылочных типов данных внутри Вашей структуры, могу предложить Вам следующий вариант:

```
// Пример пакета
public unsafe struct Packet
{
    // System.Int32 и без того является типом значения
    public int userID;
    // Для примера сделал фиксированное поле
    public fixed byte userMessage[256];

    public Packet(int userID, byte[] userMessage)
    {
        this.userID = userID;
        fixed (byte* id = this.userMessage)
            for (int i = 0; i < 255; ++i)
                id[i] = userMessage[i];
    }
}
```

Расширение для демонстрации:

```
public static class StructExtensions
{
    public static byte[] Zip<T>(this T Obj) where T : struct
    {
        // Получим размер, занимаемый объектом
        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(Obj);
        // Сюда будем читать данные
        byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
        // Выделим память и получим указатель на выделенный блок
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
        try
        {
            // Пишем данные структуры в неуправляемый блок памяти
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(Obj, ptr, false);
            // Копируем данные
            Marshal.Copy(ptr, bytes, 0, size);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // Даже в случае ошибки память следует освободить
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
            throw exception;
        }
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        return bytes;
    }

    // Не надо создавать расширения для стандартных типов
    // Здесь я это делаю чисто ради наглядности примера
    public static T Unzip<T>(this byte[] Bytes) where T : struct
    {
        // Получаем дексриптор (указываем, что он закреплен, чтобы сборщик мусора не баловался)
        GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(Bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        try
        {
            // Читаем структуру из блока памяти
            T theStructure = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(T));
            handle.Free();
            // Возвращаем ее
            return theStructure;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // Даже в случае ошибки память следует освободить
            handle.Free();
            throw exception;
        }

    }

}
```

И сам тест:

```
// Подготовим тестовый массив данных
byte[] userId = Enumerable.Range(0, 255).Select(x => (byte)x).ToArray();
// Инициализируем объект
Packet packet = new Packet(10, userId);
// Сериализуем его и тут же десериализуем обратно
Packet endDataPacket = packet.Zip().Unzip<Packet>(); // userID == 10, userMessage = [0..255]
```

Заметьте, что метод `.Zip()` вернет нам массив байт длинной `260` (4 на `int` и 256 на массив), то есть ровно столько, сколько мы и храним

Суть данного метода в том, что мы просто *копируем* участок памяти, занимаемый структурой, в массив байт. Потом этот массив мы можем точно так же записать в участок памяти, отведенный под аналогичную (хотя бы по размерам) структуру
Именно поэтому важно **отказаться** (в рамках данного метода) от ссылочных типов, ибо на их *"месте"* находятся указатели на иные блоки памяти, где и хранятся их данные. Тем самым в рамках одной и той же машины копирование структуры, которая включает в себя ссылочные типы (вроде массивов), пройдет успешно (если указатели на объекты не сменились), а вот при передаче такого блока на удаленную машину Вы получите результаты весьма неожиданные (точнее,  *неопределенные*)

Я не знаю конкретики Вашей ситуации, так что не принимайте мой совет за истину
Ибо это просто совет, который к тому же и не для всех ситуаций применим)

Comment: Вы ответили на 2 моих вопроса, возможно даже не подозревая об этом :) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/878436/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82/878504

Comment: @LLENN, Вы не против, если я тогда вторую часть ответа транспортирую в тот вопрос? Чтобы на случай, если кому-то еще понадобится (а оно понадобится), можно было легко найти

Comment: Да, так будет лучше.

Comment: @LLENN, отлично) Тогда вечером немного перепишу пример и отвечу)