# Проблема с маршалингом fixed-полей структуры

Tags: c#, .net

Есть некая структура, преобразовывается в массив байт, далее необходимо сделать покрытие тестами данные упаковки и распаковки на локальной машине. Все бы ничего, но иногда случается так, что необходимо полностью сверить массив `fixed byte UserData[4192]` на факт повреждения данных при передачи через сеть. Тут случаются следующие проблемы, хотелось бы сравнить полностью все байты содержащиеся в пакете с данными. Попытки обратиться к `byte*` через `[]` не дают такого сделать, описывая это тем что необходимо использовать выражение `fixed`. При попытке копировать указатель в выражении `fixed`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < endPacket.PacketSize; i++)
{
    fixed (byte* id = endPacket.UserData)
    {
        fixed (byte* d = _packet.UserData)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(id[i], d[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

> error CS0213: Получить адрес фиксированного выражения с помощью
>   оператора fixed невозможно.

Что само себе противоречит выдавая ошибки если его не использовать, т.е. обращаться так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < endPacket.PacketSize; i++)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(_packet.UserData[i], endPacket.UserData[i]);
}
```

При этом, если поместить указатель на структуру в выражение `fixed` вот так:

```
fixed (Network.Packet* ptr = &_packet)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < endPacket.PacketSize; i++)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(ptr->UserData[i], endPacket.UserData[i]);
    }
}
```

то все прекрасно работает.

Почему так происходит, и почему только так можно обращаться к данным содержащимся в структуре?

Структура:

```
public enum PacketType
{
    Voice,
    Text,
    Command,
    Exit
}

public unsafe struct Packet
{
    public PacketType PacketType;
    public bool IsPartial;
    public fixed byte UserData[MaxBufferSize];
    public readonly int PacketSize;
    public const int MaxBufferSize = 4192;

    public Packet(PacketType packetType, byte[] userMessage, out int bufferOutSize)
    {
        int userMessageSize = userMessage.Length;

        PacketSize = userMessageSize > MaxBufferSize ? MaxBufferSize : userMessageSize;
        bufferOutSize = PacketSize;
        IsPartial = userMessageSize > MaxBufferSize;
        PacketType = packetType;

        fixed (Packet* a = &this)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < PacketSize; i++)
            {
                a->UserData[i] = userMessage[i];
            }
        }

#if DEBUG // Для теста на случай провала
        for (int i = 0; i < PacketSize; i++)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"UserData[{i}] = {UserData[i]}");
        }
#endif
    }
}
```

---

Upd: Имеется решение костылем, для упаковки распаковки структуры, т.к. `Marshal.PtrToStruct` а так же `Marshal.StructToPtr` не дали необходимых результатов:

Структура:

```
public enum PacketType
{
    Voice,
    Text,
    Command,
    Exit
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public unsafe struct Packet
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] private readonly int _packetType;
    [FieldOffset(4)] private readonly bool _isPartial;
    [FieldOffset(8)] private readonly int _packetSize;
    [FieldOffset(12)] private fixed byte _userData[4192];

    /// <exception cref="IndexOutOfRangeException"></exception>
    internal byte this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
            if (i > _packetSize)
            {
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException(
                    $"Max value of index cannot be greater than value of PacketSize. Current value is {PacketSize}");
            }

            byte data;

            fixed (void* self = &this)
            {
                data = Marshal.ReadByte(new IntPtr(self), 12 + i);
            }
            return data;
        }
        set
        {
            fixed (void* self = &this)
            {
                Marshal.WriteByte(new IntPtr(self), 12 + i, value);
            }
        }
    }

    public PacketType Type
    {
        get
        {
            PacketType result;
            fixed (void* self = &this)
            {
                result = Marshal.ReadInt32(new IntPtr(self), 0).To<PacketType>();
            }
            return result;
        }

        internal set
        {
            fixed (void* self = &this)
            {
                Marshal.WriteInt32(new IntPtr(self), 0, (int) value);
            }
        }
    }

    public int PacketSize
    {
        get
        {
            int result;
            fixed (void* self = &this)
            {
                result = Marshal.ReadInt32(new IntPtr(self), 8);
            }
            return result;
        }

        internal set
        {
            fixed (int* data = &_packetSize)
            {
                *data = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsPartial
    {
        get
        {
            bool result;
            fixed (void* self = &this)
            {
                result = Marshal.ReadInt32(new IntPtr(self), 4) == 1;
            }

            return result;
        }

        internal set
        {
            fixed (bool* data = &_isPartial)
            {
                *data = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public Packet(PacketType packetType, byte[] userMessage, out int bufferOutSize)
    {
        int userMessageSize = userMessage.Length;
        _packetSize = userMessageSize > 4192 ? 4192 : userMessageSize;
        bufferOutSize = _packetSize;
        _isPartial = userMessageSize > 4192;
        _packetType = packetType.To<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < _packetSize; i++)
        {
            this[i] = userMessage[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Да, выглядит сумбурно и странно, но такая работа с памятью гарантирует мне что упаковка и распаковка данных произойдет корректно.

Расширения упаковки/распаковки структуры:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T To<T>(this object self)
    {
        return (T) self;
    }

    public static unsafe byte[] Zip(ref this Packet obj)
    {
        const int size = 4 + 4 + 4 + 4192;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

        try
        {
            Marshal.WriteInt32(ptr, 0, obj.Type.To<int>());
            Marshal.WriteInt32(ptr, 4, obj.IsPartial ? 1 : 0);
            Marshal.WriteInt32(ptr, 8, obj.PacketSize);

            for (int i = 0; i < obj.PacketSize; i++)
            {
                Marshal.WriteByte(ptr, 12 + i, obj[i]);
            }

            Marshal.Copy(ptr, bytes, 0, size);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
            throw exception;
        }

        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        return bytes;
    }

    public static Packet Unzip(this byte[] bytes)
    {
        GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        IntPtr ptr = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        try
        {
            Packet theStructure = new Packet
            {
                Type = Marshal.ReadInt32(ptr, 0).To<PacketType>(),
                IsPartial = Marshal.ReadInt32(ptr, 4) == 1,
                PacketSize = Marshal.ReadInt32(ptr, 8)
            };

            for (int i = 0; i < theStructure.PacketSize; i++)
            {
                theStructure[i] = Marshal.ReadByte(ptr, 12 + i);
            }

            handle.Free();
            return theStructure;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            handle.Free();
            throw exception;
        }
    }
}
```

Надеюсь есть решения таких задач попроще :)

Comment: Вы не показали самое главное: определение структуры.

Comment: Так то понятно, что `endPacket.UserData` имеет тип `fixed array`, то есть его не нужно дополнительно фиксировать.

Comment: Добавил структуру.

Comment: Есть предположение что `_packet` является `void*` указателем по аналогии с `С`, его надо `закастить` в какой-нибудь тип, а в `С#` это делается через `fixed` в том числе. Типичное приведение к типу, на мой взгляд.

Comment: @NewView: Нет, `_packet` является структурой с перегруженным индексатором.

Comment: Глянув УПД не совсем понял, какая конечная задача? Упаковывать/отсылать/распаковывать? или просто проверить соответствие полученного? Какой-то жутко сложный способ :)

Comment: Не думали кусок этого кода унести полностью на `С/С++` во внешнюю длл?

Comment: Ох, все Вы никак не победите эту задачу) Сейчас попробую посмотреть, что у Вас не так было, так как `StructToPtr` отрабатывает обычно как надо (я знаю случаи его ошибок, но Вашу структуру он должен читать корректно)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итак, я таки решил Вашу проблему
Корнем зла как раз и являлся [fixed](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/fixed-statement))

Но об этом чуть позже, для начала разберемся с остальными вопросами!

---

> Почему так происходит, и почему только так можно обращаться к данным, содержащимся в структуре?

Дело в том, что когда Вы получаете доступ к фиксированным полям извне, они уже закреплены в стеке, так что попытка повторной фиксации вызывает ошибку компиляции [CS0213](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0213).

Да и про контекст [fixed](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/fixed-statement), начиная с [C# 7.3](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-3), вообще можно забыть, ибо теперь индексирование закрепленных полей нигде не требует дополнительной фиксации.

Пример:

```
public unsafe struct TestFixed
{
    public fixed byte FixedField[1];

    // Инициализация фиксированного выражения с помощью 2 разных записей
    // Контекс unsafe обязателен!
    public unsafe TestFixed(byte[] Arr)
    {
        // Без создания новой переменной
        FixedField[0] = Arr[0];

        // C# 7.2- style
        fixed (byte* field = FixedField)
            field[0] = Arr[0];
    }
}

...

TestFixed test = new TestFixed(new byte[] { 1 });
byte getByte = test.FixedField[0]; // 1

fixed (byte* _field = test.FixedField)
    getByte = _field[0]; // CS0213, так как объект уже закреплен

byte* field = test.FixedField;
getByte = field[0]; // 1
```

---

У Вас же ошибка записи структуры в неуправляемый блок памяти посредством [Marshal.StructureToPtr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/2zhzfk83(v=vs.100).aspx) вызвана именно наличием фиксированного поля `UserData`

[Marshal.StructureToPtr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/2zhzfk83(v=vs.100).aspx) как-то странно и через раз их обрабатывает: то считает все до бита по размеру структуры, то считает только *"первый элемент"* (т.е. `N` байтов с начала указателя, где `N = sizeof(используемый фиксированным полем тип)`)

Так что лучше все таки использовать обычные *"безопасные"* структуры, управляя тем, как они хранятся в памяти и маршалируются, с помощью атрибутов

Я переписал Вашу структуру следующим образом:

```
// Укажем, что члены должны располагаться так, как мы их описали
// А также явно укажем размер структуры (в байтах):
//
// 4 на PacketType (int)
// 4 на IsPartial (пусть bool и занимает всего 1 бит => 1 байт в целых числах,
//      однако по умолчанию структуры пакуются таким образом для более быстрого доступа к элементам)
// 4 на PacketSize
// MaxBufferSize на UserData
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 12 + MaxBufferSize)]
public struct Packet
{
    public PacketType PacketType;

    public bool IsPartial;

    public readonly int PacketSize;

    // Благодаря данному атрибуту мы можем указать, что массив является
    // частью структуры, так что на его месте в памяти будет не ссылка,
    // а все элементы данного массива
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MaxBufferSize)]
    public byte[] UserData;

    public const int MaxBufferSize = 4192;

    public Packet(PacketType packetType, byte[] userMessage, out int bufferOutSize)
    {
        int userMessageSize = userMessage.Length;
        PacketSize = userMessageSize > MaxBufferSize ? MaxBufferSize : userMessageSize;
        bufferOutSize = PacketSize;
        IsPartial = userMessageSize > MaxBufferSize;
        PacketType = packetType;
        UserData = new byte[MaxBufferSize];
        // И никаких "мучений" с fixed)
        Array.Copy(userMessage, UserData, Math.Min(userMessage.Length, MaxBufferSize));
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() => UserData.Sum(x => x);
    // Проверим полное совпадение данных пакетов
    public override bool Equals(object obj) => obj is Packet packet && packet.PacketType == PacketType && packet.IsPartial == IsPartial && packet.PacketSize == PacketSize && EqualsData(packet);

    // Совпадает ли UserData у пакетов
    public unsafe bool EqualsData(Packet Packet) => Packet.UserData.SequenceEqual(UserData);
}
```

Проведем тест:

```
// Готовим данные
PacketType packetType = PacketType.Text;
byte[] userMessage = Enumerable.Range(0, Packet.MaxBufferSize).Select(x => (byte)x).ToArray();

// Инициализируем
Packet packet = new Packet(packetType, userMessage, out _);

// Получаем массив байт, а из него - новую структуру
Packet endPacket = packet.Zip().Unzip<Packet>();

// Проверяем:
bool isOk = packet.Equals(endPacket); // true
```

Как видите, теперь никаких проблем с копированием в/из памяти не возникло и все данные были обработаны корректно!

Если же посмотреть размер, занимаемый Вашей структурой в памяти, то мы получим искомые `4204 == 12 + MaxBufferSize`!

P.S. - в коде использовались методы из [более раннего вопроса по этой теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/878436/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82/879138?noredirect=1#comment1428663_879138)!

---

На этом все, проблема решена)

Опять же в качестве совета я хотел предложить следующую вещь: не надо загонять все типы пакетов в один
Если Вы можете настроить сервис на прием сообщений разной длины (сначала передается длина последующего пакета, а потом уже он сам), то создайте разные структуры под пакеты разных типов. Пусть сначала идет как раз тип пакета, чтобы Вы, считав первые 4 байта, могли знать, во что Вам десериализовать последующий массив байт. Тем самым некоторые вещи (к примеру, передачу строк) можно сильно упростить

---

Надеюсь, все Ваши проблемы наконец-то иссякли и Вы сможете идти дальше в Ваших свершениях!
Удачи Вам!

Если проблемы возникнут вновь - буду рад Вам помочь!

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из того что я использую тестирование кода, а так же `Live Unit Testing` мне постоянно при изменении структуры попадались куски кода, которые раз на раз проваливали тест работоспособности данной структуры, как пакет информации, который необходимо отправить удаленному сокет серверу, сделал все это дело без использования `unsafe` кода, и прямой работы с пямятью.

Все это дело выглядит куда проще чем могло мне показаться изначально.

Структура:

```
public enum PacketType
{
    Voice,
    Text,
    Command,
    Exit
}

public struct Packet
{
    private readonly byte[] _userData;

    /// <exception cref="IndexOutOfRangeException"></exception>
    public byte this[int i]
    {
        get => _userData[i];
        internal set => _userData[i] = value;
    }

    public PacketType Type { get; internal set; }

    public int PacketSize { get; internal set; }

    public bool IsPartial { get; internal set; }

    public Packet(PacketType packetType, byte[] userMessage, out int bufferOutSize)
    {
        int userMessageSize = userMessage.Length;
        PacketSize = bufferOutSize = userMessageSize > 4192 ? 4192 : userMessageSize;
        IsPartial = userMessageSize > 4192;
        Type = packetType;
        _userData = new byte[PacketSize];
        Array.Copy(userMessage, _userData, PacketSize);
    }

    public static implicit operator byte[] (Packet packet)
    {
        return packet._userData;
    }
}
```

Методы упаковки распаковки:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T To<T>(this object self)
    {
        return (T)self;
    }

    public static byte[] Zip(this Packet obj)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[obj.PacketSize + 12];
        List<byte> dataBytes = new List<byte>(obj.PacketSize + 12);
        dataBytes.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(obj.Type.To<int>()));
        dataBytes.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(obj.IsPartial ? 1 : 0));
        dataBytes.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(obj.PacketSize));
        dataBytes.AddRange((byte[])obj);
        Array.Copy(dataBytes.ToArray(), bytes, dataBytes.Count);
        return bytes;
    }

    public static Packet Unzip(this byte[] bytes)
    {
        int realPacketSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 8);
        byte[] data = new byte[realPacketSize];
        Array.Copy(bytes, 12, data, 0, realPacketSize);
        // параметр out должен использоваться для подготовки списка пакетов на основе полученных данных, и максимальной длины пакета данных
        Packet theStructure = new Packet(BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0).To<PacketType>(), data, out _)
        {
            IsPartial = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 4) == 1
        };
        return theStructure;
    }
}
```

На данном этапе я решил пока приостановиться, т.к. теперь длина пакета имеет не фиксированный размер, но в тоже время не превышает его максимальную длину.

Отдельная благодарность @Kir_Antipov за подачу столь хорошей идеи.